# Cakephp 3. I need a in-accessible controller action by URL

Tags: cakephp, action, visibility, cakephp-3.x

I have two public actions within my controller. I need to set delete() to inaccessible by URL for security reasons.

- The action delete() should be public so accessible from other controllers.
- I think that Authentication, Routing or Csrf are very impractical solutions.
- I did not find solutions in Controllers, Request nor Name conventions from CakePhp3 cookbook.

```
    class CommentsController extends AppController
    {
        public function add (){
           //logic to add here
        }
        public function delete ($id = null){     
          //logic to delete here
        }
    }
```

I hope help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using an action inside another controller is a good idea.

If you are going to do some logic then the right place to put it is the model.

So put you delete code inside the CommentsTable

```
class CommentsTable extends Table
{
    public function delete ($id = null){     
        //logic to delete here
    }
}
```

so when you are in another controller you can do

```
class ItemsController extends AppController
{

    public function doSomething () {
        $this->loadModel('Comments');
        $this->Comments->delete(42);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Great. delete() action is now in-accesible by URL also I can access to it from a controller. Thanks

Comment: Before your help, I was trying with  by prefixing controller method names with underscores according to cookbook 2.x. My last question is where to put functions when there is a controller without model. Thanks